# Texture Channel animated, doesn't appear in viewport

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm creating an educational video, and for efficiency, I'm using a Cyclic repeater to repeat an on-page/off-page effect.

Every loop, I have the texture channel switch to the next image, rather than duplicating all the objects/animations. This works properly and appears when rendering the animation, but *does not appear in the viewport*. It sticks to the original UV image that was mapped.

Is there a way to have this change appear in the viewport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer no, I don't think there currently is one unfortunately.

I think its a known limitation of the viewport system and a long time to-do list item as stated [in the wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Development/Todo/Animation#Animation_System), [in this bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T42034) and [in this one too](https://developer.blender.org/T45714)

Comment: Bummer. I guess I'll have to work around it.