# How can I see the result of an animated texture in the viewport?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I am animating the textures of a model, but when I scrub through the frame timeline the texture is displayed as a still image. I am making an animation were the textures are of eyes and they keyframe different textures to perform a blinking animation, but the only way I can see it is when I render the animation. How do I see the texture keyframes while scrubbing through the timeline instead of them appearing as still images?

Comment: I'm using the internal render currently.

Comment: In that case http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54187/texture-channel-animated-doesnt-appear-in-viewport/54189#54189

Comment: Yes. Whenever I play the animation, the first texture keyframe is shown, but when it passed the second texture keyframe (a different texture) it does not update to show it in the 3D view unless I manually click the texture.