# Why is there no motion when adding clips into Image texture node in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, image

No matter what I choose, it shows me only the 1st frame as if it was a single image although I choose the Movie option and the number of frames is more than 1.

How can I fix it?

I tried different projects and different videos, it is always the same.
Also I'm not sure if it's the same problem, but I've seen lots of tutorials using Images as Planes feature and they could see a picture on a plane in Material View. I can't.

Comment: I see you've tagged this under Cycles.  The link following explains how to get images onto planes and see them in Material Mode as per the second part of your question. Cycles may well do it differently however. - the link - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71513/what-order-to-texture-a-3d-object/71603#71603

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54187/texture-channel-animated-doesnt-appear-in-viewport